# How to use a "for" loop in R to create different time series

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, time-series

I am new to R and I am trying to solve the following: i need to create 40 different seasonally adjusted time series for 40 different cities. The 
 code, that works, for one time series looks as follow (Stockholm in this case)

```
stockholmtsdecomp = stl(stockholmts[,5], window="periodic")

des_stockholmts <- seasadj(stockholmtsdecomp) #
```

where the time series stockholmts already exists (as well as for the other 39 cities)

How to iterate over cities?
one way to solve it is to rewrite this 40 times for each city. I'd like to do it in a loop to save time. What i have in mind is (just 3 cities here)

```
lanlist=list('stockholm', 'oslo', 'madrid')

for (i in lanlist)
{
  x=(paste(i,'ts', sep=""))
  y=(paste(i,'tsdecomp', sep=""))
  z=(paste('des_',i,'ts', sep=""))
  y = stl(x[,5], window="periodic")
  z <- seasadj(y)
}
```

which obviously doesn't work. Any neat solution?

thanks!

Comment: Great and intuitive answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions `as.symbol()` and `eval()` to retrieve the variable names you are building in the loop as language symbols and evaluate them *when they are used as inputs* (e.g. `x` in your code).

You can use function `assign()` to create a variable whose name is given by a variable *when they are used as outputs* (e.g. `y` and `z` in your code).

Here is a proof of concept example that shows how this works using your variables `x` and `z` on two time series corresponding to two cities:

```
oslots = c(3.5, 2.1, 1.7)
madridts = c(1.9, 2.8, 3.1)
lanlist=list('oslo', 'madrid')
for (i in lanlist)
{
  x = paste(i, 'ts', sep="")
  cat("Processing time series '", x, "'...\n", sep="")

  z = paste('des_', i, 'ts', sep="")
  assign(z, eval(as.symbol(x))[1])
  cat("The first value of time series '", x, "' is: ", eval(as.symbol(z)), "\n", sep="")

  cat("\n")
}
```

which should output the following:

```
Processing time series 'oslots'...
The first value of time series 'oslots' is: 3.5

Processing time series 'madridts'...
The first value of time series 'madridts' is: 1.9
```

I trust you will be able to take these concepts to your code that performs seasonal and trend decomposition of time series.

Comment: As a new contributor I kindly point you out to the instructions of what to do if you think an answer you received is helpful for your question or solved your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Following these guidelines help the community. Thank you! :)